# existence of minimum distance from a point to a compact subset in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose E is a non-empty compact subset of a metric space (X, d) and x0 ∈ X. Show that
there exists x ∈ E such that d(x0, x) = inf{d(x0, y)| y ∈ E}, meaning x is the nearest point to
x0

for showing this I thought of assuming the nearest point x is not in E, then since the $d(x,x_0)$ is an infimum there can be constructed a subseries of ${d(x_0,y)| y∈E }$ convergent to the inf $d(x,x_0)$

from this I wanted to show that you can find a series {y} in E convergent to x.

but this will need the distance function to be continuous, but we know nothing about the metric space and the distance function defined on it.

Answer (score 1):

The metric function $d \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in the sense that if $(x_n) \to x_0$ and $(y_n) \to y_0$, then $d(x_n, y_n) \to d(x_0, y_0)$. The map $x \mapsto d(x_0, x)$ is continuous on the compact set $E$ and therefore attains a minimum on $E$.